# How to bundle classes from different module to jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have a main project (say A), it contains module B and module C. Module C is a dependancy for module B. Apart from that I want to add all the classes of module C to the jar of module B. By adding C as a dependency in maven pom file works fine. But module B jar runs independantly and wants module C classes (compiled) at runtime.

How can I do that with maven.?
I'm using JIdea 12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First add C as a dependency to B

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>A</groupId>
        <artifactId>C</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

then use maven shade plugin in the pom file of module B as follows

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${artifactId}-${version}</finalName>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/project-summary.html), and configure it to shade module C into module B or directly into the main project.